# Help with focus in jquery

Tags: jquery, focus

I have two button on my confirmation popup (popup_ok & popup_cancel), I want to restrict focus on either of the two buttons untill user decides what he/she wants to do. Uptill now im doing the following

```
$("#popup_cancel").blur(function() {

    $("#popup_ok").focus();
    $("#popup_ok").focus();

});
```

but this is not working, kindly guide me to better approach

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have to expand more on what you want to achieve. I for one, have no idea.

Comment: Could you please rephrase what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you mean "not working"? What happens when you focus the cancel button?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's not practical to perform a `focus()` inside a `blur()` event, but if you insist, I advice you to use a small timeout to force the focus to execute outside of the event bubble:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#popup_ok").focus(); }, 10)
```

(Updated based on Matt's comment to prevent using `eval()`)

Comment: It's recommended to pass a function to `setTimeout` (and `setInterval` for that matter), instead of a string. Passing a string applies `eval()`, and we all know that `eval()` is bad :). `setTimeout(function() { $('#popup_ok').focus(); }, 10);`